# link style not showing in safari

Tags: css, menu, safari, hyperlink

The submenu links show up white in safari on my macbook.

They should show black, as they do in every browser (ie, ff, chrome) on Windows 7.

This happens on my site: http://www.impactshred.com

Why don't the style work in Safari?

Comment: if you put `http://` before your URL's, then they will turn into links

Comment: Have you following the LAHV scheme? (i.e. `a:link, a:active, a:hover, a:visited`)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating this:

```
#navigation ul li.hover ul li a,
#navigation ul ul li a,
#navigation ul ul li a:visited
```

To use `:link`

```
#navigation ul li.hover ul li a:link,
#navigation ul ul li a:link,
#navigation ul ul li a:visited
```